# Stream Video/Audio from TV Tuner Card in .NET/WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, video-streaming, video-capture, tv-tuner

I'm looking for a way to stream video and audio from a tv tuner card using coaxial cable to a custom application in .NET. I have seen the DirectShowNet Library and I think it might work for what i need but i was just curious if there are any other options out there. Paid or free, it doesn't matter. I just want to be able to create an application that displays the TV feed and allows me to change the channel and the volume. Is DirectShowNet the way to go or is there a way to embed Window Media Player into an application and get the TV feed from that? Any information would be real helpful, thank you.

Comment: Ever make any progress on this?

Comment: not really. kinda put it on hold for now. 2 things that i did find but didn't look into yet are http://www.hauppauge.co.uk/board/showthread.php?t=21923 and http://www.avermedia.com/avertv/Upload/SDK/index.html. maybe they will be of help to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were using the MediaLooks SDK some time ago to stream content from several cams to WPF-clients.
Not sure if it helps you getting the stuff out of the tv-card b/c of protection stuff, but you can give it a try.

http://www.medialooks.com/products.html